# How to use recursion in Maple

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recursion, maple, euclidean-algorithm

I was trying to write a procedure that would compute a simple linear equation using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.
I was thinking of a procedure like the following:

```
solveEeaMatrix := proc (a::list, b::list) 
 local c::list;  
 c := a -iquo(a[1],b[1])*b;  
 print(c);  
 while (c[1] <> gcd(a[1],b[1]) do 
 ...
```

I am basically stuck at this part as

1)  I don't know how to setup a multi-dimensional array that could dynamically grow(as a possible solution).

2) I can't come up with a recursive function that could possibly take care of this.

In short, if I am given for example an equation like:  `84*x+203*y = 14`

I will transform it into 2 linear equation as follow:
`row0 := [203, 0, 1]
 row1 := [84, 1, 0]`
 Subsequently, I will perform the following:

```
c := a -iquo(a[1],b[1])*b;
```

Where `a`and `b` are both lists and arguments of the procedure and `c`being another list and a local variable.

But I don't know how to do the following programmatically:

```
row3 := row1-iquo(row1[1], row2[1])*row2;
row4 := row2-iquo(row2[1], row3[1])*row3;
row5 := row3-iquo(row3[1], row4[1])*row4;
and so on ...
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) I think this is a question for the [Maple tag on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maple) as it is a programming question. 2) Can you give an example of a more complicated example and how that would look like? To give a better idea of how the procedure is supposed to expand the row equations.